# How to call associated function with array or tuple type?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I can define an associated function `foo` for an array like this:

```
pub trait T {
    fn foo();
}

impl<X> T for [X; 2] {
    fn foo() { panic!("Whatever") }
}
```

But how do I now call this function? I noticed that syntax like `[usize;2]::foo()` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** You need to use angle brackets: `<[usize; 2]>::foo()`.

**Long answer:**

If you'll look in [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html), you'll see the syntax:

> *CallExpression* :
>       [*Expression*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html) `(` *CallParams*<sup>?</sup> `)`

Inside *Expression*, you have [*PathExpression*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/path-expr.html). There are two kinds of *PathExpression* s: [*PathInExpression*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#paths-in-expressions) and [*QualifiedPathInExpression*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#qualified-paths). *PathInExpression* is a simple path of the form `a::b::c::<generics>::d::<generics>` etc.. This is what you use when you type e.g. `String::new()` or `String::from("abc")`.

*QualifiedPathInExpression*, on the other hand, has the form *QualifiedPathType* (`::` *PathExprSegment*)<sup>+</sup>, or in simple words, *QualifiedPathType* followed by one or more instances of two colons then *PathExprSegement*. *PathExprSegment* is defined as a name (identifier) optionally followed by two colons and generics: i.e., `foo` or `foo::<a, b, c>`.

And what is *QualifiedPathType* ? It is defined as `<` [*Type*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#type-expressions) (`as` [*TypePath*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#paths-in-types))<sup>?</sup> `>`, or a type enclosed in angle brackets, optionally followed by `as` and a *TypePath*, which is very similar to *PathExpression* with some differences.

*Type* is any Rust type syntax: a path (e.g. `a::b<generics>` or `a::b::<generics>`, trait objects (`dyn Trait`), `impl Trait`, tuples (`(T1, T2, T3, ...)`), arrays (`[T; N]`), slices (`[T]`), references (`&T` or `&mut T`, potentially with a lifetime), and more.

All of this means that when you call a method, unless the method type is a simple path - that is, has the form `a::b::c`, potentially with generics, you *must* enclose the type in angle brackets - `<Type>::method()`. That includes arrays, slices, references, tuples, function pointers (`fn(Args) -> Ret`), and more. `[usize; 2]::foo()` is not a valid Rust syntax, only `<[usize; 2]>::foo()` is.

Of course, there is another reason to use this form: UFCS (Universal Function Call Syntax). When you want to specify the trait (usually for disambiguition), you must use the form `<Type as Trait>::method()` (this is the "(`as` *TypePath*)<sup>?</sup>" we saw).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the fully qualifidied syntax `<Type as Trait>::function()`. Here is your example:

```rust
pub trait Trait {
    fn foo();
}

impl<X> Trait for [X; 2] {
    fn foo() {
        panic!("Whatever");
    }
}

fn main() {
    <[usize; 2] as Trait>::foo();
}
```

See it on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=36586729af6f86f85f7240d1c339185b).